# In PowerShell V2, how to have named parameters in a method on a static class?

Tags: powershell, static, named-parameters

The following didn't parse

```
[x.y]::z -Param1 some_value
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling .NET methods from PowerShell, you use C# style comma separated args in parens syntax e.g.:

```
[x.y]::z(some_value)
```

In PowerShell, named parameters are a feature of PowerShell commands (functions, advanced functions, scripts, cmdlets, workflows) only.